# How do I restore the start menu after killing explorer.exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows, start-menu

In Windows 7 64 bit, I killed explorer.exe, and then via the task manager do file->run "."

This method has always caused the start menu to reappear, but right now it doesn't.

After killing a rogue explorer.exe process, what's the best way to restore the start menu?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Via the Task Manager go *File* -> *New Task (Run...)* and enter "explorer.exe" ("explorer" by itself may also work.)

This will start a new instance of the explorer process (and therefore restore your Start Menu.)

Comment: So, what does running "." do? It always used to be equivalent to running "explorer.exe" - did this change sometime?

Comment: Did doing it work in Win7 ever or was this something you used to do under XP? Under Windows 7 (maybe Vista too) running "." or just . brings up a Windows Explorer window at the System32 folder. I believe (and someone can correct me if I am wrong) that under Win7 explorer.exe and "Windows Explorer" can work independently of each other, were as in XP they may have been linked so starting Windows Explorer would also start an explorer.exe process. Again, just speculation on my part, specifying explorer.exe works regardless.

Comment: I didn't even know the "." worked.  Since 96, you've been able to simple use "explorer.exe" from the taskman to restart explorer.

Comment: Not sure if it ever worked in Windows 7, it's been a while since I had to use this :)

Comment: This is old so I hate to comment, but for me, it just opens Libraries (windows explorer) and not the taskbar... any ideas why and an alternate method to use?

Comment: (duh) `c:\windows\explorer.exe` did the trick

Comment: This worked perfectly. In case you do not have a task manager open, ctrl alt del and start task manager.

Comment: worked OK for me on Windows 10

Comment: If you have a command line prompt open, Patrick Moore's suggestion needs to be tweaked to c:\windows\system32\explorer.exe.