# Windows 10 does not search for Help files (CHM)

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, chm

There was a feature in Windows 8 I liked very much: possibility to find a help file using the system search. I mean the search that is invoked when you press the Win key and start typing the thing you need or press the Win-S shortcut.

I have applications that are installed along with offline help files in the CHM format. These application adds shortcuts for both executable (e.g. **MyApp 7**) and help file (e.g. **MyApp 7 Help**) to the StartMenu folder. When I start searching and type *MyApp 7 Help*, Windows 8 returned the shortcut to the CHM file to me.

Windows 10 does not do this. It offers me to execute the **MyApp 7 Help** command which definitely is not what I want. How can I tune the search engine and return the possibility to search for the CHM help files in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on this. I'm not sure if you are experiencing a bug or you want to increase your index, so I'm going to provide both options here:

1. You should be able to fix your issue by incresing your Windows Indexing. You can do this by **a)** hitting the Windows key followed by searching for 'Indexing Options', **b)** from there click 'Modify', **c)** tick the box for 'Local Disk (C:)', and **d)** click 'OK'. Then close the Indexing Option window and you may need to wait a good 30 minutes for the index to rebuild.

Also, you may want to 'Rebuild' the index through the advanced options (cleaner) which will prompt you with a message stating that "Rebuilding the index might take a long time to complete...". I'd recommend doing it but it will take longer, but if you don't and run into issues try it and click 'OK' to the message.

**Note:** You may also want to enable 'Treat similar words with diacritics as different words' in the advanced options, but this is a preference thing as it is more like searching the web.

2. If Cortana isn't working properly, see article:
   [Windows 10 Search can't find ANY applications. Even calculator](https://superuser.com/questions/947392/windows-10-search-cant-find-any-applications-even-calculator)

Reinstalled Cortana using the following procedure:

- Open an elevated Command Prompt window (press Win+X, and then press
  A)
- Type start powershell and press enter
- Run the command (in one line):

  Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

Hope this helps and Good Luck!

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.