# How can I run Windows 8 search on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I have the "can't open the start menu" bug, and while researching it I tried a tip that Windows 8 search is still available somewhere in the control panel. It worked, but I forgot how to access it. Where is this command?

Comment: Does using the keyboard shortcuts `Winkey` + `Q` or `Winkey` + `s` also not work?

Comment: I remember that the comment where I found this complained that the Windows 8 search could not be bound to `Win+S`. I'll check those shortcuts next time I lose my start menu, but this question really isn't about the start menu bug, it's about executing the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I thought to limit my search to SuperUser and found the answer again in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/947392/windows-10-search-cant-find-any-applications-even-calculator#comment1304373_947392).

> if you go to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs and open the shortcut "Search", it opens the "Search Everywhere" feature from Win 8.

Very handy when Windows 10 search is down!