# Windows 10 does not find any/most desktop apps

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I have Windows 10 installed and from what I can tell, everything is working fine.
The issue I have is with my start menu.

If I press the windows key and start typing "Calcul" or even the full word "calculator", (or "Calc" as it is called as well), it does not find **anything** at all.

Same for "Notepad" or "Skype".

But other apps can be located, for example "Control" finds a best match and some apps as well as some settings.

If I type "Outlook" then Outlook 2013 is in the list, (as I have it installed).
But if I type "Excel" then it does not find Excel 2013.

It looks like my indexing kind of works... or not all items have been indexed.

What could the issue be?

I have windows 10.0 (Build 10240), and I am up to date from what I can tell, (Update & Security) > Windows Update > Check for Updates = "Your device is up to date.".

Comment: The first thing you should try when you have any kind of system related error is to open a command line window as an administrator and run `sfc /scannow`

Comment: Ran it, (as administrator), and after a while... "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations".

Comment: next idea: run cmd as administrator and type `ren %windir%\System32\AppLocker\Plugin*.* *.bak`, reboot, than give a feedback

Comment: if that doesn't help, you might try to follow the steppes of this answer: http://superuser.com/a/955711/447369

Comment: Hum, the folder %windir%\System32\AppLocker is empty, (and so is %windir%\SysWOW64\AppLocker), is that normal?

Comment: yup, that was just a guess that might have caused the problem

Comment: Re-the other link you posted, it completed but all the same really. In my case, Cortana is not supported, but it says that it should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

> I have Windows 10 installed and from what I can tell, everything is working fine. The issue I have is with my start menu.

This implies that you've only just installed Windows 10. The indexing can take several hours, so it may be the index has not finished yet. Unlikely, but possible.

More likely, you need to re-index it

> The index requires almost no maintenance. However, if the index can't
>   find a file that you know exists in an indexed location, you might
>   need to rebuild the index. Rebuilding the index can take several
>   hours, and searches might be incomplete until the index is fully
>   rebuilt.
>
> Open Indexing Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the
>   Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type
>   indexing options, and then click Indexing Options.
>
> Click Advanced.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted
>   for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or
>   provide confirmation.
>
> In the Advanced Options dialog box, click the Index Settings tab, and
>   then click Rebuild.  Administrator permission required If you're
>   prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the
>   password or provide confirmation.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/change-advanced-indexing-options)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but the upgrade was over a week ago, I only noticed now that certain apps are 'missing'. If I look at the indexing, I have ~1.5 million files indexed and it says "Indexing complete", but I will re-build it and report back it.

Comment: Does it work on the second attempt? Meaning, click start, type, get no results. Close the start menu (by clicking the desktop or pressing escape), the hit the start button and type again. @SimonGoodman

Comment: Nope, it does not, I type "calculator" using the 2 steps and it does not find it, I then try with Excel and it also does not find it, (but it does find some Apple Excel.ipa file in the first and second attempt).

Answer (score -1):

That issue might accrue due to not properly installed window or may be a you are using pirated one. I will suggest you to reinstall W10 to get rid off this issue . I will suggest you to contact windows help center too

Comment: I don't think you can get a 'pirated' copy of windows 10, (and if you can, I certainly don't have one or even know how to get one).
In any case, it is an upgrade from Windows 7, everything worked fine in the upgrade, no error(s), warning.

Comment: Oh dear some of my friend was using Windows 0 before its announcement . Might be My word ' pirated' copy ' may be not suit here bt What i want to explain you  was that you should download from officel site

Comment: I has nothing to do with official site or not.
I don't even know where to get it, other than from the official site.
More importantly, your assumption is ridiculous, something does not work, it must be pirated, go to the official site. How ridiculous.

Comment: I would be very surprised if a small issue like this was caused by a broken/pirated OS. (There would be bigger problems, like Windows Update being broken or the system file watcher freaking out.)