# Using wildcards in Windows 10 search for applications

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

To start any application, I hit <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>
(the Windows Key) to start search, and then type `fire` to search for Firefox, and then click on it when it appears.

When I want to start, e.g., WinSCP, I sometimes remember only the `SCP` part. But it seems not possible to search `?SCP` or `*SCP` for applications. It is always showing up only the applications starting with the search string.

Comment: [Windows Search](http://superuser.com/questions/947392/windows-10-search-cant-find-any-applications-even-calculator?rq=1) has not changed in Windows 10 despite it being connected to Cortana. So there is something specific going with your configuration.

Comment: I tried it - I searched for `cel` and it showed me files. I then searched for `*cel` and it found Ex**cel** straight away

Comment: @Dave does this also work directly in the box next to start launcher? For me it only works if i go to the search for apps section.

Comment: I did exactly as you describe. Do you need to rebuild your index?