# Windows 10 Indexing Options Cannot be Accessed (and Windows Search is Not Working)

Tags: windows-10, search-indexing

On a fully updated, freshly rebooted Window 10, I'm logged in as the domain administrator.

Windows 10 search (via start-menu > type something) is not working, so I thought I'd try re-indexing, however, when I attempt to go to Indexing Options I get this error:

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Same result after killing SearchUI.exe.