# Windows 10: Cant Find Applications Through Search Box

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

If I log in and then search for a program (like Device Manager, Calculator, Notepad) etc. from the Cortana search box, Windows will find it and I can launch it from the result list.

However, if I try to look for more programs, Windows search is dead. Nothing is listed.

If I sign out and log back into Windows again it works. But the behavior is I can do one search only and then the search feature craps out.

Anyone else have this problem and have a solution?

Comment: Related: [Windows 10 Search can't find ANY applications. Even calculator](http://superuser.com/questions/947392/windows-10-search-cant-find-any-applications-even-calculator)

Comment: If you create a new user account does the behavior still exhibit itself?

Comment: I could swear my Windows 10 worked perfectly before I read this question. Now it happens to me too. This opens an interesting avenue: Could an update be responsible?

Comment: I am encountering the same problem on my Windows 10 x64 desktop as well as my x86 laptop.  Everything *was* working perfectly this past weekend.

Comment: use an alternative Startmenu and not this Win10 crap one: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557. this search is fast and works

Comment: What worked for me is what Ramhound posted in the related link. I did not have to Kill Explorer as all the suggestions in there posted. I just deleted the Top Views registry entry for that exact key (ef8) and restarted Windows: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{ef87b4cb-f2ce-4785-8658-4ca6c63e38c6}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Comment: The solution seems to be have been taken off a Microsoft community post with a problem that has existed since 2010 explained here: https://goo.gl/clYqCP

Comment: There is a hotfix for this. Seems that Microsoft has never bothered to fix this problem in subsequent releases of Windows. They never say exactly what folder type this is. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977380

Comment: As I said earlier, I was having the exact same problem and was able to alleviate it by [rebuilding the Search Index](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/58569-search-index-rebuild-windows-10-a.html) overnight.